# I have a problem with the blending of 2 textures depending on the angle of PoV

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, pyopengl

I am trying to blend 2 textures in order to simulate an lenticular surface effect i.e.
I want as I gradually change the angle of the pov the one texture should prevail over the other. The way I am trying to do this is via this fragment shader right here where i am trying to define an angle where this smooth change will happen and after i pass this threshold only one texture should be visible but right no matter how I change this code to the edges of my pov only the first texture is being shown and the second one is being shown only at the [85,105] spectrum where I actually would like the blending to happen. In order for you to understand I would like to simulate the behavior of this coin from this website https://www.phasmatic.com/. Can you please guide me as to what should I do?

```c
uniform sampler2D textureSampler1;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler2;
in vec2 UV;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = texture(textureSampler1, UV);
    vec4 color2 = texture(textureSampler2, UV);

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(vec3(viewMatrix[0][2], viewMatrix[1][2], viewMatrix[2][2]));
    vec3 normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    float angle = acos(dot(normal, viewDir));

    float blendAngleThreshold = radians(10.0); // Threshold angle for transitioning to single texture view

    float weight1 = smoothstep(blendAngleThreshold, blendAngleThreshold + 0.05, angle);

    float weight2 = 1.0 - weight1;

    // Apply grating effect based on UV coordinates
    // float gratingIntensity = sin(UV.y * 1200.0) * 0.5 + 0.5; // Adjust the parameters as desired
    // weight1 *= gratingIntensity;
    // weight2 *= gratingIntensity;

    float numSlices = 5.0;
    float sliceWidth = 1.0 / numSlices;
    float displacement = angle * sliceWidth;
    vec2 modifiedUV = UV + vec2(displacement, 0.0);

    vec3 reflectionDir = reflect(viewDir, normal);
    vec4 reflectionColor = texture(textureSampler1, modifiedUV);

    float reflectionIntensity = 0.5 + 0.5 * cos(angle);
    reflectionColor *= reflectionIntensity;

    float metallicIntensity = 1.0;
    vec4 metallicColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 metallic = mix(color1, metallicColor, metallicIntensity);

    vec4 blendedColor = weight1 * (metallic + reflectionColor) + weight2 * color2;

    blendedColor.a = 1.0;

    fragColor = blendedColor;
}
```

I tried this but it seems to produce the same baffling result

```
glsl

 vec4 color1 = texture(textureSampler1, UV);
    vec4 color2 = texture(textureSampler2, UV);

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(vec3(viewMatrix[0][2], viewMatrix[1][2], viewMatrix[2][2]));
    vec3 normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    float angle = acos(dot(normal, viewDir));

    float blendAngleThreshold = radians(10.0); // Threshold angle for transitioning to single texture view

    vec3 rightDir = normalize(vec3(viewMatrix[0][0], viewMatrix[1][0], viewMatrix[2][0]));
    float rightness = dot(rightDir, viewDir); // How much the view is from the right side

    float weight1 = smoothstep(blendAngleThreshold, blendAngleThreshold + 0.05, angle) * step(0.0, rightness);

    float weight2 = 1.0 - weight1;
```

Comment: The image on the website looks very much like an environment map to me. That's usually done with a cube map and reflecting the view direction along the normal.

Comment: So the problem does not lie with the shader?